# JavaScript is a NaN, but I know it's not?

Tags: javascript, nan

I have the following two functions...

```
function splitTitleString(titleText)
{   
    var titleText = titleText;
    var temp = new Array();
    temp = titleText.split(' - ');
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var warningExpResp = 7200000;
    var expRespDateTimeTicks = 0;
    var slaDateTimeTicks = 0; 

    if(temp[0].length > 0)
    {
    slaDateTimeTicks = getTicks(temp[0]);
    }

    if(temp[1].length > 0)
    {
        expRespDateTimeTicks = getTicks(temp[1]);
    }

    var returnTicksArray = new Array(slaDateTimeTicks,expRespDateTimeTicks);

    return returnTicksArray;
}
```

And...

```
function  warning(titleText, serverDateTime, warningLengthMins, warningType)
{
    var warningLengthTicks = warningLengthMins * (60 * 1000);
    var ticks = new Array(splitTitleString(titleText));
    var sla = parseInt(ticks[0]);
    var resp = parseInt(ticks[1]);
    var serverTicks = getTicks(serverDateTime);

    // some other work....
}
```

The problem I have is 'resp' is always NaN even though 'ticks[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)' most definitely is?

PS: I'm not a [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) developer so please be nice if it's poor code.

Comment: I totally don't understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Where is it that you're using `resp` that it comes back `NaN`?

Comment: [OT] FWIW, since I know you're new to JS, this line has no effect: `var titleText = titleText;`  The `titleText` parameter is already defined within the function in exactly the same way that `var` defines it (and you're free to change its value within the function; doing so has no effect outside the function, JavaScript variables are always passed by value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `splitTitleString()` returns an array value.

However, when you define `ticks`, you say `var ticks = new Array(splitTitleString(titleText));`. You define an array which consists of one element-  the return value of splitTitleString.

As a result, `ticks[0]` is obviously not an integer, it is an array!

EDIT: To fix it, rewrite your function like this:

```
function  warning(titleText, serverDateTime, warningLengthMins, warningType) 
{ 
    var warningLengthTicks = warningLengthMins * (60 * 1000); 
    //I removed the "new Array()" from the next line
    var ticks = splitTitleString(titleText); 
    var sla = parseInt(ticks[0]); 
    var resp = parseInt(ticks[1]); 
    var serverTicks = getTicks(serverDateTime); 

    // some other work.... 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are accessing `resp` outside the `warning()` function, your problem is that by using `var resp`, you define a new variable that is visible *only within the containing function*. If resp is supposed to be a global variable, remove the `var` keyword and you should be fine.

See here for a nice rundown on local and global variables in Javascript: [Variable scope and the var keyword](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/reference_js_intro_ex.html)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Pekka correctly said, parseInt prefers to have a radix parameter. From the docs:

> If the radix parameter is omitted,
>   JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> - If the string begins with "0x", the
>     radix is 16 (hexadecimal)
> - If the
>     string begins with "0", the radix is 8
>     (octal). This feature is deprecated
> - If the string begins with any other
>     value, the radix is 10 (decimal)

Answer (score 0):

What are you passing as "titleText" parameter, check if it is indeed an int. I mean [1]